# Getting an Array from my ResultSet and adding it to an Object

Tags: java, sql, arrays, tostring

I'm trying to use ResultSet.getArray() to grab an int[] array from my database. I'm using postgreSQL, DBeaver, and Java.

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
            
            ArrayList<Theater> theaterList = new ArrayList<>();
            
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                Theater t = new Theater(
                        rs.getInt("theater_id"),
                        rs.getArray("theater_numbers"),
                        rs.getString("theater_loc")
                        );
                
                theaterList.add(t);
                
                return theaterList;         
            }
```

Error message: "The constructor Theater(int, Array, String) is undefined"

I keep getting flagged for not having a constructor of the appropriate type:

```
import java.sql.Array;

public Theater(int theater_id, Array theater_numbers, String theater_loc) {
        super();
        this.theater_id = theater_id;
        this.theater_numbers = theater_numbers;
        this.theater_loc = theater_loc;
```

Here's the beginning of the class:

```
public class Theater {
    private int theater_id;
    private Array theater_numbers;
    private String theater_loc;
```

Not sure how to make the types agree with one another.

How do I make the types agree?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact error message. The code you have provided looks like it should work with the `Theater` constructor, but just to check, is your Theater method inside a Theater class with the exact same spelling `public class Theater` ?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question to contain the class declaration.

Comment: Your class `Theater` is not extending any other class, so calling `super();` inside the constructor will not work. Simply remove `super();` or correctly make Theater extend the class that you are trying to call the super method for. If that does not fix your issue then please note what you tried, and also note exactly which line is throwing the error message.

Comment: I compiled your code locally and did not see that error. I did, however, notice you have a "return" statement inside the while-loop. Perhaps that's intentional, but it looks like a mistake (if there's a set of result to iterate over, and a List to add results to, why eject after adding just one?) Anyway, I suspect your situation is less of a programming error and more to do with your environment (tools, compiler, editor, something in there).

Comment: Thank you, Kaan. Yes, it was my editor. I was using Spring Tools; tried it in eclipse and got no error. That while loop I think was just to show functionality quickly and dirtily. My instructor wrote it and I kind of had the same question. Thank you!